# Heavy Metal-ish animated picture with kidnapped princess

Tags: story-identification, animation

I just saw scenes of this on another site, but without much information about it. A black-haired and scantily clad princess is left in her castle to learn about the elements when creatures similar to D&D-style orcs kidnap her. Somehow separated from the orcs (if that's what they are), said princess is found by a dim-witted troll-type being who takes her to his mother, a red haired witch. The red-haired witch learns the princess is sought by a guy named Necron (spell?).

Like I said in the header the film is animated, in colour, and while I didn't see any actual nudity it does strike me as adult-oriented.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is almost certainly 1983's *Fire and Ice*. Plot summary from [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=fire%20and%20ice%20movie):

> This fantastical animated movie by cult filmmaker Ralph Bakshi finds the villainous Nekron and his mother, Queen Juliana, attacking the human race from their frigid fortress. Creating mass destruction with huge glaciers, Nekron and Juliana incur the wrath of Larn, a warrior whose entire village was destroyed by ice. When Nekron's underlings kidnap the beautiful Princess Teegra, Larn sets out to rescue her, assisted by the fierce and enigmatic Darkwolf.

Here's Princess Teegra, she looks just as you recalled:

[image: Animated still frame depicting a woman, from shoulders up, with black hair]

Comment: @T.E.D. I wrote this at about 4am my time and just forgot. Thanks for bringing it to my attention, it's fixed now

Comment: Also notable in this film: Teegra is a character who actively tries to help herself. She's not necessarily successful, but she doesn't sit around waiting for <s>Conan</s>--I mean Larn--to come to her rescue.